# Context class not recognizing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to fetch the phone's IMEI number and other details. For that I need the Context class reference. I am using the TelephonyManager class for the same. Following is my code with build.gradle file and I m getting error in Context class reference. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
TelephonyManager tm (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String IMEINumber=tm.getDeviceId();
```

Error at Context class.

Following is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kk.kk.uniquevalues"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this from an activity? And please post the full **logcat** of the error.

Comment: Do you have the `Context` class imported? If that code is in a `Context` class - e.g., an `Activity` or `Service` - you don't really need the `Context.`. Also, you're missing an `=` in your first line of code.

Comment: @Vucko Yes I am calling it from Activity, and here is my Logcat.

Comment: Error:(16, 68) error: cannot find symbol variable Context                            Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: @MikeM.Yes I have imported the Context class. And there is '=' sign in the first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

have you added required `manifest permission` to `manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Yes I've added the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to the manifest.

Comment: Error:(16, 68) error: cannot find symbol variable Context                            Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: is this a activity or what ?
and show the whole log for this error
and code

Comment: Yes this is the activity and I am getting that much only in error log. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have problem related to the SDK.
**Try the next step to "Refresh" your IDE (android studio)**

1. Let Gradle rebuild your auto-genrated files by click **Build | Rebuild** 
 
2. Also try [Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: I did it, nothing happened :(